# PlayFramework 2.2 - Scala - Read Mixed Arrays

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-json

I'm trying to use the reader/combinator things to parse an array that contains mixed data-types, but I'm not sure how to specify a reader for such a thing. I have some JSON like this:

```
{
  "stuff": [1, 2, true, null, "false", "hahaha", 5, "8"]
}
```

I want to parse all of this into a string-representation, but when I just try to use a reader of `List[String]` I get parse exceptions. I imagine something like this:

```
 implicit val mixedArrayReader = (
       (__ \ 'not).readNullable[List[JsValueWrapper]].map(opt => opt.map(list =>
             list.map { wrapper : JsValueWrapper =>
                val parsed : String = wrapper match {
                      case b : JsBoolean => if (b.value) "1" else "0"
                      case n : JsNumber  => n.value.toString
                      case s : JsString  => s.value
                      case JsNull        => "null"
                      case u             => u.toString  // unknown
                   }
                parsed
                }
          ))
 )
```

However, since there is no reader for `JsValueWrapper`, I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by implementing a customized Reads[String], then use `Reads.list` to turn it into a reader of `List[String]`, then use that reader as usual. Prefer to pass those particular readers explicitly versus defining implicits for them in order to not hide Play's default  `Reads[String]`.

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads

val myReader: Reads[String] = Reads[String](value => JsSuccess(value match {
  case b : JsBoolean => if (b.value) "1" else "0"
  case n : JsNumber  => n.value.toString
  case s : JsString  => s.value
  case JsNull        => "null"
  case u             => u.toString  // unknown
}))

val listReads = Reads.list[String](myReader)
```

Then, in a combined reader you can write something like:

```
implicit val objReader =
  (__ \ 'not).readNullable(listReads)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution by thesamet is probably the most straight forward.  I think your solution will work if you use `.readNullable[List[JsValue]]`, `JsValue` is the super type of all Js* types, the wrapper you should never need to work with directly, it only exists to help ease creating JSON objects and arrays.

Another more functional and flexible solution (note that this solution handles errors much better) that you could use is:

```
val anyValueAsStringReader =
  implicitly[Reads[BigDecimal]].map(_.toString) or
  implicitly[Reads[String]] or
  implicitly[Reads[Boolean]].map(if (_) "1" else "0") or
  implicitly[Reads[JsValue]].map(_.toString)

val mixedArrayReader = (__ \ 'not).readNullable(Reads.list(anyValueAsStringReader))
```